# Amazon EC2 gives no disk space but my instance has space

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-server

So i have an instance that supposedly has a lot of free space.

I have installed Postgres and when i try to import a dump it tells me my disk is full. I did a `df -h` and saw that in fact `xvda1` is full, but what about `xvdb ?

it has a lot of free space, how can i use that for my Postgres database??

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  7.5G  1.1M 100% /
udev            1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           376M  184K  375M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb       394G  199M  374G   1% /mnt
```

Comment: Which instance size are you using? is xvdb an EBS volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xvdb` is most likely an the [Amazon EC2 Instance Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) volume (also called an *ephemeral volume*, in contrast to an [Amazon EBS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonEBS.html) volume) and you almost certainly do not want to use it if you value your data, *except if you exactly know what you are doing and are prepared to always have point in time backups etc.*:

> Ephemeral storage **will be lost on stop/start cycles** and **can
>   generally go away**, so you definitely don't want to put anything of
>   lasting value there, i.e. **only put temporary data there you can
>   afford to lose or rebuild easily**, like a swap file or strictly
>   temporary data in use during computations. Of course you might store
>   huge indexes there for example, but must be prepared to rebuild these
>   after the storage has been cleared for whatever reason (instance
>   reboot, hardware failure, ...).

See my answers to the following related questions for more details:

- [Will moving data from EBS to ephemeral storage improve MySQL query performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10120863/45773)
- [how to take backup of aws ec2 instance/ephemeral storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10751034/45773)